# Issue starting tomcat 8 on aws server

Tags: java, tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm using an aws ec2 server with a ami image with linux/Tomcat8

http://thecloudmarket.com/image/ami-ce5d82bd--aws-elasticbeanstalk-amzn-2015-09-0-x86-64-tomcat8java8-hvm-201510302155

Which is handy, but when I try and start tomcat,

```
$ sudo service tomcat8 start
Starting tomcat8: touch: cannot touch ‘/usr/share/tomcat8/logs/tomcat8-initd.log’: 
No such file or directory  
[FAILED]
```

No Bueno :(
I'm not really the most familiar with tomcat, so I'm not sure what the best step forward to trouble shoot.

Any ideas what this could be?

Comment: Looks like the dir doesn't exist.  `mkdir -p /usr/share/tomcat8/logs` to make it.  That does seem like an odd place for a log file directory, though...

Comment: Try running `ls -l /usr/share/tomcat8` and adding the results of that to your question.

Comment: @JohnHascall that worked perfectly, thanks. Wonder why it wasn't created in the first place :?

Comment: I guess they assumed it would always be there.  Apparently a poor assumption.

Comment: I think the root of your problem is that you have chosen an Elastic Beanstalk AMI image, but you aren't using Elastic Beanstalk. Elastic Beanstalk would start Tomcat with a specific logs directory, but since you aren't using EB Tomcat is trying to write to the default logs directory, which apparently doesn't exist on this AMI.

Answer (score 1):

Who would of thought the fix could be so simple (and obvious) :)

To fix this issue simply create the log folder.

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/logs
```

The server will start fine. Who would have thought :D
Props to  [John Hascall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2040863/john-hascall) for the insight.

Comment: That's the logs directory, not the log file, that you had to create. That directory is usually created as part of the Tomcat install.

Comment: Updated the verbage, meant to say folder. Yeah not sure why it wasn't created. Odd.

Comment: I added a comment above explaining why the directory didn't exist. The AMI you picked really wasn't meant to be used the way you are using it.

Comment: Yeah my plan was to set things up an ec2 server then take a Snapshot to move things over to EBS. As I'm Not entirely familiar with configuring the server via say Chef on EBS.

Comment: That's really not the way you should use Elastic Beanstalk. You configure your beanstalk application via .elasticbeanstalk and .ebextensions files which describe your environment configuration and then Elastic Beanstalk manages that configuration for you whenever it creates a new server instance. Also note that the abbreviation EBS = Elastic Block Store, EB = Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Yeah its not ideal I'll give you that, and it will probably make it harder work on down the road if I have to make changes to the server. Unfortunately with the time crunch we're on its going to have to work for the time being. Thankfully there isn't a ton of server setup involved, and I already have RDS running and working well along side the server. So long term it should just be a matter of spinning up a new EB server with the proper setup and all should be well.  - Thanks for the clarity on the abbreviation :)